# How can I detect external microphone in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

How can I detect, from within my application, if an external microphone is plugged in the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let route = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute

for port in route.outputs {
    if port.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
        // Headphones located
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Post OP change in question -

When app is running you need to register for `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` to listen to the changes like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"audioRouteChangeListener:", name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil)

dynamic private func audioRouteChangeListener(notification:NSNotification) {
    let audioRouteChangeReason = notification.userInfo![AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as UInt

    switch audioRouteChangeReason {
    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue:
        println("headphone plugged in")
    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue:
        println("headphone pulled out")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I detect if any microphone plugged in the device while the app is working?. I mean I want to see an instant notification everytime when I plug the microphone .

Comment: Always happy to help :-)! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With `AVAudioSession` you can list the `availableInputs`

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    _ = try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, withOptions: [])

    print(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs)
```

It return an array of `AVAudioSessionPortDescription`. And you can have the portType "wired or builtIn" microphone type.

PS : It only work on real device not on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

**swift3:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChangeListener(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)

@objc private func audioRouteChangeListener(notification: Notification) {
    let rawReason = notification.userInfo![AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as! UInt
    let reason = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: rawReason)!

    switch reason {
    case .newDeviceAvailable:
        print("headphone plugged in")
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        print("headphone pulled out")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With swift 2.0 this code works

```
func audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (notif: NSNotification){
    let userInfo:[NSObject:AnyObject] = notif.userInfo!
    let routChangeReason = UInt((userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey]?.integerValue)!)
    switch routChangeReason {
    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue:
        print("Connected");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue:
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
        } catch _ {
        }
        print("Connected");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.CategoryChange.rawValue:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```